# Behavior of code with alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I just wanted to understand if my method has some code that shows an alert dialog and after that some other code, then when the alert dialog is shown and I have not clicked any button, will my code below the alert **dialog.show()** line wait for the dialog to cancel or it will simply be executed without waiting for the response from the alert dialog? Please help me understand this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowLog.this);
builder.setMessage("Do you really want to delete the "+size+" records?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //Doing some work          
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();

       }
    });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

SomeWork();
Somework1();
```

I want to know when SomeWork(); will be executed. Is it just after showing the alert dialog or after clicking Yes or No of the alert dialog?

Comment: I tried to trace and found it is not waiting for the alert dialog to be closed. It simply executes the Somework() /Somework1() without waiting. Later when I click Yes/No the code defined for the buttons only executes. Anyways thanks a lot for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AsyncTask for doing backgroung process

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to understand if the code after alert.showDialog() will wait for the alert dialog to be closed or it will be executed even if the alert dialog is still shown.

Comment: it will wait t for the alert dialog

Comment: I tried to trace it. It is not waiting. It simply executes the other statements without waiting for the alert dialog to be closed.

Comment: There are three mothod as onPreExecute(...),doInBackground(...) andonPostExecute(...) do all process in do in doInBackground(...) and then it will wait.like if u want network operation (fatech data from server) or get data from database (fatch more images from db) etc. can u send a code what u are doing so that i can more do for u.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with android_dev, use an AsyncTask:

- show your dialog on onPreExecute(...)
- do your work in doInBackground(...)
- hide your dialog on onPostExecute(...)

Anyway, it depends on what is the interaction that you want between the dialog and the work you have to do. You might want to execute a task based on some input coming from the dialog.

I think we need to have more details...